# Android counter >= value not correct

Tags: android, listener, counter

I have a few buttons that add and subtract. I would like a display to pop up if the counter falls to 0 or below that says game over. I have the winGame(); function set under each button clicklistener to check the counter total. 
**The issue I am having is that no matter what the value of the counter is, it always shows the textbox saying game over. Every time a button is clicked to add or subtract a total auto brings up the texbox. Also worth noting is the counter starts at 20 when the app launches.
Here is the code.

```
            void winGame() {
    if (counter1 <= 0 || counter <=0 );
    String text = "Game Over";

    // Build a dialog box and with the result string and a single button
    AlertDialog.Builder game = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    game.setMessage(text).setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new 
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)   
            {
                    // do things when the user clicks ok.
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = game.create();

    // Show the dialog box.
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A subtle little bug...

```
if (counter1 <= 0 || counter <=0 );
```

should be

```
if (counter1 <= 0 || counter <=0 )
```

Or is this what you want?

```
void winGame() {
    if (counter1 <= 0 || counter <=0 )
    {
        String text = "Game Over";

        // Build a dialog box and with the result string and a single button
        AlertDialog.Builder game = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        game.setMessage(text).setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new 
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)   
            {
                // do things when the user clicks ok.
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = game.create();

        // Show the dialog box.
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: And `String text` will need to be declared outside the `if` statement - but at least that would end up being a compile time error.

Comment: void winGame() {
  if (counter1 <= 0 || counter <= 0) {
  }

  String text = "Game Over";                          It is still doing the same thing, every time a button is clicked adding or subtracting it displays the game over textbox

Comment: Of course, `if (counter1 <= 0 || counter <= 0) { }` is equivalent to `if (counter1 <= 0 || counter <= 0);` They both do absolutely nothing.

Comment: Yeah that was exactly what I wanted. Side question, and feel free to not answer it as you have already helped me very much, if I wanted a reset button to be displayed alongside the OK button on the game over pop up? I know how to make the button display but not to reset the values of the counter.

Comment: I should have tried to type that code out before asking. thank you very much for your help!